# Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel-5

Im trying to add the HtmlServiceProvider with Laravel 5. But when i write - "php artisan serve" in terminal i get error -

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found
```

I already have these things in configs.

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

and

```
'Form'      => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html'      => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

- i cant run all php artisan commands.
  Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider` line from your `config/app.php` providers section since you are not using that package.

Also might be worth clearing the compiled file if that isn't enough.

Comment: I have already removed that line from config. But terminal keeps showing that error. E: I dont know how to clear that file.

Comment: its also possible another package might be trying to load that provider.  `bootstrap/cache/compiled.php` is where the compiled file would be.

Comment: Now i changed cache file, but page where i want create a form, says - Class 'Form' not found.

Comment: and you have the 'Form' alias in `config/app.php` aliases?

Comment: Yes, i checked all files. Thank you for help. I have found some commands, php artisan optimize
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache